# Plot a graph (x = y) in C# using OpenTK?

Tags: c#, .net, opentk

How to plot a simple graph (x=y) in C# using OpenTK ? both at Windws Form Application and at console App ?? What methods do use to plot that graph ?I'm new to this tool so a a good link or toutorial will help me a lot ....

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow ! You have at first do some googling. Then come here and ask a specific question. That you want is fairly easy and I am certainly that it is included in a tutorial for OpenTK. Thanks

Comment: for example [VBO: How to draw a simple triangle](http://www.opentk.com/node/2292)

Comment: I google it but i was unable to find a good link and some that i found related to graphs that were unable to understand for me at this level as i just started to learn this tool ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You should start with [Learn OpenTK in 15'](https://web.archive.org/web/20160818021658/http://www.opentk.com/doc/chapter/0)
2. For a simple x=y graph, copy-paste the code snippet provided in the link above and remove the game.RenderFrame part and replace with code snippet pasted just below

   ```
   game.RenderFrame += (sender, e) =>

   {
        GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);

        GL.Begin(PrimitiveType.Lines);
        GL.Color3(Color.White);
        //YAxis
        GL.Vertex2(0.0f, 2.0f);
        GL.Vertex2(0.0f, -2.0f);

        //X-Axis
        GL.Vertex2(2.0f, 0.0f);
        GL.Vertex2(-2.0f, 0.0f);
        GL.End();

        GL.Begin(PrimitiveType.Points);
        // Plotting the Graph
        GL.Color3(Color.DeepSkyBlue);
        for(float i=0;i<2.0;i=(float) (i+0.001))
        {
            GL.Vertex2(i,i);
        }
        GL.End();
        game.SwapBuffers();
   };
   ```

Comment: I run this code as per your instruction .. i came to know that this code is for Console Window .. Now i want it to draw at Web Forms (Asp.net) using OpenGL .. Can you help me to get started with it ...