# Dynamic/Moving Graphs plotting libraries/framework in C#

Tags: c#, graph, opentk, freeglut, tao-framework

Which will be better to plot the dynamic or moving graphs( like ECG or dynamically changing data) in C#.
I concluded two library framework using Open GL

```
     - Open TK 
     - TaoFramework 
     - FreeGlut
```

Which One I should chose and Is there a dedicated library (.netcharting library) for plotting graphs which supports Moving Graphs in C#.

thnx

Answer (score 1):

(Disclaimer: I am the author of OpenTK and have used the library to plot EOG, OCT and various other animated datasets before.)

Do you need a UI? (Buttons, checkboxes, menus?) In that case, your best bet is OpenTK (GLControl) combined with Windows.Forms for the UI elements. If you simply wish to display waveforms, you can also use OpenTK (GameWindow) which also runs on mobile phones and tablets.

A quick google search on "opentk graph" or "opentk plot" returns multiple relevant results:

- [Plot a graph (x = y) in C# using OpenTK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24629056/plot-a-graph-x-y-in-c-sharp-using-opentk)
- https://oxyplot.codeplex.com/discussions/462121
- https://github.com/isawred2/Music-Decompiler/blob/master/GUI/Plot.cs
- https://graphics.cs.wisc.edu/Papers/2013/MG13/splatterplots-final.pdf

FreeGlut would let you create an OpenGL window, but then you'd have to use OpenTK or Tao to draw into it, so this is not very useful on its own.

Tao hasn't had a release for close to a decade now and is quite outdated (OpenGL v2.1 only, whereas OpenTK supports v4.5). There is very little reason to start a new project using Tao at this point.

Comment: Honored to get the reply from the Author of OpenTK.I hope the OpenTK can support me for autoscaling of the graphs, pausing/running of the graphs and also some hacking of the graph data( say marker on the graph if the value of any axis goes > delta). I exclude using FreeGlut and Tao for the time being !

Comment: Just keep in mind that OpenTK itself just gives you access to OpenGL commands. If you are familiar with OpenGL you can use it to build a graphing component, otherwise it is going to take some learning (or you can search for a prebuilt graphing library that uses OpenTK.)

Comment: thnx, looking for C# bindings of OpenTK !! will google it out !

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy. You have to use slope point form i.e.

`y - y1 = m * (x - x1)`

Refer my example code in C# [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14327/Drawing-medical-waveforms-using-a-Windows-Mobile).